# "Content is not allowed in prolog." IntelliJ Ultimate

Tags: ktor

The file I can download, for some reason I am getting a "Content is not allowed in prolog." error.

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.3 (Ultimate Edition)

This is what my build.gradle.kts looks like:

```
val ktor_version: String by project
val kotlin_version: String by project
val logback_version: String by project

plugins {
    application
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.21"
}

group = "com.pnerdyx"
version = "0.0.1"
application {
    mainClass.set("com.pnerdyx.ApplicationKt")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()    
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-auth:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-auth-jwt:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-locations:$ktor_version")    
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-host-common:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-webjars:$ktor_version")
    implementation("org.webjars:jquery:3.2.1")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-thymeleaf:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-gson:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktor_version")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logback_version")
    testImplementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-tests:$ktor_version")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version")
}
```

- What went wrong:

  Execution failed for task ':compileKotlin'.

  - Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.

  > Could not resolve com.typesafe:config:1.3.1.

  Required by:

  > project : > io.ktor:ktor-server-core:1.6.1

  > Could not resolve com.typesafe:config:1.3.1.
  >
  > > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/typesafe/config/1.3.1/config-1.3.1.pom

  > - Content is not allowed in prolog.

  > - Could not resolve com.typesafe:config:1.3.1.

  > - Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/typesafe/config/1.3.1/config-1.3.1.pom
  >   > Content is not allowed in prolog.

Link to [project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j9km6Lrkl5HFkZQhkYOm80iKM8yAtYPY/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your problem on an empty project. Could you please share a complete project or file an issue in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=KTOR?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman I have added the link to the project at the end of my post above.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it using your project. Maybe you had some network problem accessing https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/typesafe/config/1.3.1/config-1.3.1.pom. Try to open it in a browser and check XML for validness.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman It seems to be something might be wrong with my gradle.  When I switch to maven, it is able to build without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, turned out to be a path issue for Gradle in IntelliJ.  I also had several version of gradle installed, decided to clean that up, and put the latest in the opt directory, and add the path to my environment file.